# RecyclerView: Go to a position not scroll to

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is there a way with the RecyclerView to go directly to a nominated position rather than scroll to it. (If the distance to the target is large and the item layout complex, scrolling can take an acceptable amount of time.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `ScrollToPosition` to go directly to a position on `RecyclerView`

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(your_position)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#scrollToPosition(int)

Comment: Yep, that's the one I needed. Fooled by the name. ;(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position)` instead of  `smoothScrollToPosition(position)`.