# Why recyclerview with paging not working properly?

Tags: android, kotlin

Hy,

So, I have 2 fragments, the first one is a browser fragment, the second one is a detail fragment.

I noticed that, if I scroll down a lot, for example to the 200th item, and I go to the item details fragment, and after that I navigate back, the recyclerview automtically scrolls up herself for the 60th item.

After that I saw the code, and I noticed that, I use paging library, and in the config I set up the page size to 30, and the InitialLoadSizeHint to 2*pagesize which is 60.

So I think that, this is cousing the problem, when I navigate back, the InitialLoadSizeHint is 60 but the actual recycler view position is 200.

If I increase the pagesize to 100, after back navigation the recycler view jumps for the 200th item.

Additional information, I use LiveData to pupulate data from database.

How can I fix that? What did I wrong?

```
**Pagedlist config**
        val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
            .setPageSize(model.pageSize)
            .setPrefetchDistance(model.pageSize)
            .setInitialLoadSizeHint(model.pageSize * 2).build()

**List observer**
        viewModel.listData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            Timber.d("submitting new list")
            baseBinding.get()?.progressBar?.visibility = View.GONE
            adapter.get()?.submitList(it) {
                setAppBarScrolling()
            }
            
            baseBinding.get()?.productBrowserProducts?.scrollToPosition(prefManager.RECYCLERVIEW_LAST_POSITION)
        })
```

Comment: Hello, I think your view is recreated, this is why your paging library shows the 60 first items. Is there any way (with this library) to jump to a specific item, or with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33558477/recyclerview-go-to-a-position-not-scroll-to), and implement a solution to save or return the clicked position, to display it when you go back on this screen. My two cent

Comment: Thanks, I already tried, inside the observer of list, but it isn't helped unfortunately.

Comment: what kind of observer are you talking about? Could you put some more code? let's find a solution

Comment: I updated the qestion, as you can see, I saved the last recycler view position into sharePref, and when the list arrived, I try to scroll to the saved position. And yes, I checked the variable contains the current position

Comment: Indeed, have you tried to put breakpoints into `scrollToPosition()` function to see if it's really called with the good parameter?

Comment: Yes I tried, and everything looks good, and I also tried scroll to position with offset

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I made a big mistake, because inside the fragment onCreateView method I triggered my filter, and because of this, the observer is called, and although the viewModell didn't destroyed, still reloaded the data. So I deleted this line, and problem solved.